# Can't lock Touchpad on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: touchpad

My *multimedia* shortcut for locking the touchpad is not working anymore, but there is still the icon on the screen showing the touchpas has been locked.
Over multimedia shortcuts are working. 
Locking it with some extensions like `touchpad-indicator` works but I would like to make the shortcut works again.

My computer is an Asus VivoBook S15 (S510UA-BQ447T)

Thanks

Some of the Content of the Output of `xmodmap -pke | grep XF86`

```
keycode 199 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
keycode 200 = XF86TouchpadOn NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOn NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOn
keycode 201 = XF86TouchpadOff NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOff NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOff
```

Comment: this may be related. https://askubuntu.com/q/1131466/739431

Answer (score 1):

Since Toggling Button on Keyboard is not working as expected..

here is a workaround..

1. run `xmodmap -pke | grep TouchpadToggle`
2. check the symbol on keyboard which is given for Toggling of Touchpad.. in mycase it is on F5 #Change F5 with your key on keyboard
3. run `xmodmap -pke | grep F5`
4. run `xmodmap -e "keycode 71 = XF86TouchpadToggle"` #Change 71 with your output.

Example:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep TouchpadToggle
keycode 199 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
$ xmodmap -pke | grep F5
keycode  71 = F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5
xmodmap -e "keycode 71 = XF86TouchpadToggle"
$
```

that's it.. Please note that you will loose the original function of F5 key with this workaround.. eventhough xmodmap shows upto 8 keys can be configured, but it seems with Function Keys it is not happening..

From `man xmodmap`

`The  list of keysyms is assigned to the indicated keycode (which may be specified in decimal, hex or octal and  can be  determined  by running the xev program).  Up to eight keysyms may be attached to a key, however the  last  four are  not  used in any major X server implementation.  The first keysym is used when no modifier key is  pressed  in conjunction  with  this  key, the second with Shift, the third when the Mode_switch key is used with this key and the  fourth  when both the Mode_switch and Shift keys are used.`

Please note that you can bind `XF86TouchpadToggle` to any key you wish, all you need is just go through `man xmodmap`

I have tried this in dual boot Windows10 and Ubuntu 18.04.. as you said in comments, in Windows10 <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> key worked as expected and my <kbd>F5</kbd> key has the symbol for TogglingTouchPadOn/Off and this did not work in Ubuntu 18.04.. seems the reason is clearly visible that by default it is mapped to keycode 199 which I dont have with my present keyboard. So it is need to map the keysym `XF86TouchpadToggle` to any desired key.

[image]
.