# After disabling Touchpad from system settings it disappeared 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, system-settings

I disabled my touchpad from system settings and now there is no touchpad section there anymore.

[image: here is the settings screenshot]

Am i missing something?

output of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam: HP Webcam                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: yes. there was Touchpad On/Off, i made it off and now it's gone

Comment: i was trying to add a shortcut key to enable/disable the touchpad from keyboard and i wrote script which enables and disables from command line using xinput and it works fine, not anymore though, but i didn't install anything or change any settings. i just clicked the on/off in system setting window

Comment: but now it doesn't work at all..

Comment: BTW after you asked about rebooting, i restarted again and when i'm in the screen that i write the user password ( idk what it's called) the touchpad was working, then ubuntu started and it stopped workinf again!

Comment: purge and install didnt work everything is the same.

Comment: OK! i used gsettings to enable it: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'enabled'`   now it's working and i can see in the GUI as well. but still after disabling from GUI i have to use gsettings to enable it.. thanks for the help and this link: https://askubuntu.com/q/1131466/739431

Comment: Do not hesitate to post your resolution as an answer and accept it. For me, disabling the touchpad does not make the touchpad section to disappear from the settings pane. This is strange and erroneous behaviour indeed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i used this to solve the issue: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'enabled'`
but still even after it comes back, if you disable from the settings pane, you have to use gsettings again to make it work!